# Regular expressions in shell script

Tags: regex, shell

I am trying to search a line in a log file, based on the regular expression. When I use below command I am getting the proper output. Platform: Solaris, Shell: Bash

```
grep 14:[00-29]
```

**O/P:** Apr 02 14:07:35 [192.168.162.117.113.169]

But when I use the below command I am getting blank output

```
grep 14:[00-29]:[00-59].
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[00-29]` matches only the characters 0, 1, 2 and 9.

`[00-59]` matches only the characters 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 9.

The `[]` construct creates a **character class**, not a numeric range.

You might want `grep -E 14:[0-2][0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is not doing what you think. What it is actually doing is saying `get me 14:[ONE number that is 0, 0-2 or 9]:[ONE number that is 0, 0-5, or 9]`. You should change it to `14:[0-9]|([0-2][0-9]):[0-9]|([0-5][0-9])`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another regex. For example this makes it:

```
grep "14:[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" file
          ^^^  ^^^   ^^^  ^^^
           |    |     |   any number
           |    |    from 0 to 5
 from 0 to 2   any number
```

See the output:

```
$ grep "14:[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" file
Apr 02 14:07:35 [192.168.162.117.113.169]
```

---

The first one was matching but casually:

```
$ grep 14:[00-29] file
Apr 02 14:07:35 [192.168.162.117.113.169]
          ^^
          | |
          | 7 is not matched
          [00-29] matches this 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of these regex:

```
14:[00-29]
```

and

```
14:[00-29]:[00-59]
```

are incorrect and they aren't really matching values from `0 to 29` for example.

For range of 00 to 59 you can use:

```
\b(0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])\b
```

And for the range of 0 to 29:

```
\b(0[0-9]|[12][0-9])\b
```

Comment: Wouldnt this match 99? I think you need to put a paren around the second set of char classes

Comment: The numbers given here are 0-padded, so the ranges you're using might not be quite right.